# Do remote files I open get saved in a temporary location?

Tags: php

For example, if I download files from some other server with the `copy()`  function.

Comment: I rephrased your question a bit. A code example wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 0):

Copy takes as second parameter the destination.
Why should it store anything in **/tmp**?

Answer (score 0):

This function requires a source and a destination directory to be specified by you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) of this function. It requires a destination.

There is also a complete section on [handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) in the manual.